# Vue Get Editable Inline SVG from External Link

Tags: javascript, svg, vue.js

I am creating a Vue app which pulls in content from another website (via Wordpress REST API) and am having trouble getting an SVG to load into a Vue component so that it can be manipulated via css and js.

Here is my component so far:

```
<template>
    <div id="svg-siteplan"></div>
</template>

<script>
    import axios from 'axios';

    export default {
    name: 'svgsitemap',
    props: ['svgurl'],
    data() {
        return {
            svgerror: '',
            svgContent: '',
        };
    },
    methods: {
        getContent() {
            $('.plot-outline').hide();
            $('.plot-status').css({
                fill: '#ff6600',
            });
        },
        outputContents() {
            axios.get(`${this.svgurl}`)
            .then((response) => {
                this.svgContent = response.data;
                $('#svg-siteplan').html(this.svgContent);
            })
            .catch((err) => {
                this.svgerror = err.data;
            });
        },
    },
    mounted() {
        this.outputContents();
        this.getContent();
    },
};


</script>

<style lang="scss" scoped>
    .plot-status {
        fill: deepPink;
        transition: fill .3s ease-out;
        stroke: #444444;
    }
</style>
```

The component is passed the source URL (`svgurl`) in a `v-for` loop in a parent component e.g. `http://example.com/uplaods/my-svg.svg`

This will show the SVG but I am unable to manipulate it using CSS or javascript.

If I just copy the SVG code and paste it into the component then I am able to manipulate it, but using `v-html="svgurl"` or using axios/ajax to get the file and append it to the div stops this.

The SVG is being manipulated on the wordpress site, from which the Vue app is pulling the content, but to display the SVG on there I was able to use `file_get_contents()`. Is there a similar function in javascript/Vue that outputs the contents of an SVG file?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: https://vuejs.org/v2/cookbook/editable-svg-icons.html

Comment: The SVG files are coming from an external source though, they're not saved as assets in the app.

Comment: I think this is irrelevant, because url is url... you can point to the other sites' images too, not only your's.